# Get coordinates from the pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have done something like this:

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("cde.pdf");
        TextWithPositionExtractionStategy S = new TextWithPositionExtractionStategy();
        PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader,1,S);


             Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
            Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
            string x1 = curBaseline[Vector.I1].ToString();
            string x2 = curBaseline[Vector.I2].ToString();
            string x3 = topRight[Vector.I1].ToString();
            string x4 = topRight[Vector.I2].ToString();
```

But,what i got is the coordinates of a string,not a word.How can i modify the code so that i can get the word coordinate.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your aim: Do you search **one** specific word on a page and want to get the single set of coordinates of that word? Or do you want to retrieve the respective coordinates of **all** words on the page? Whichever it is, you will have to program a somewhat intelligent `RenderListener'.

Comment: my aim is to retrieve the respective coordinates of all words on the page,thanks for your help, but,can you a specific interpretation,because i am very new to itextsharp.Thank again for your help.