# Retrieve the respective coordinates of all words on the page with itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

my aim is to retrieve the respective coordinates of all words on the page,what i have done is

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("cde.pdf");
TextWithPositionExtractionStategy S = new TextWithPositionExtractionStategy();
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader,1,S);

Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
Vector topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(curBaseline[Vector.I1], curBaseline[Vector.I2], topRight[Vector.I1], topRight[Vector.I2]);
string x1 = curBaseline[Vector.I1].ToString();
string x2 = curBaseline[Vector.I2].ToString();
string x3 = topRight[Vector.I1].ToString();
string x4 = topRight[Vector.I2].ToString();
```

But,what i got is the coordinates of a string,which contains all words of a line,not a word.For example the content of the  pdf is "i am a girl",what i got is the coordinate of "i am a girl",but not the coordinates of "i" "am" "a" "girl".How can i modify the code so that i can get the word coordinate. Thanks.

Comment: A word IS a string. Show us exactly what you're getting and compare it to exactly what you want.

Comment: The text segments in a PDF are not necessarily starting or stopping at word boundaries. Thus, you will have to split text segments or merge them.

Comment: @mkl,thanks,i know what you say,but i don't know how to do.Can you give me more help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get coordinates from the pdf using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703006/get-coordinates-from-the-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm mostly working with the Java library iText, not with the .Net library iTextSharp; thus, please ignore some Java-isms here, everything should be easy to translate.)

For extracting contents of a page using iText(Sharp), you employ the classes in the parser package to feed it after some preprocessing to a `RenderListener` of your choice.

In a context in which you are only interested in the text, you most commonly use a `TextExtractionStrategy` which is derived from `RenderListener` and adds a single method `getResultantText` to retrieve the aggregated text from the page.

As the initial intent of text parsing in iText was to implement this use case, most existing `RenderListener` samples are `TextExtractionStrategy` implementations and only make the text available.

Therefore, you will have to implement your own `RenderListener` which you already seem to have christianed `TextWithPositionExtractionStategy`.

Just like there is both a `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` (which is implemented with some assumptions about the structure of the page content operators) and a `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` (which does not have the same assumptions but is somewhat more complicated), you might want to start with an implementation that makes some assumptions.

Thus, just like in the case of the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`, you in your first, simple implementation expect the text rendering events forwarded to your listener to arrive line by line, and on the same line from left to right. This way, as soon as you find a horizontal gap or a punctation, you know your current word is finished and you can process it.

In contrast to the text extraction strategies you don't need a `StringBuffer` member to collect your result but instead a list of some "word with position" structure. Furthermore you need some member variable to hold the `TextRenderInfo` events you already collected for this page but could not finally process (you may retrieve a word in several separate events).

As soon as you (i.e. your `renderText` method) are called for a new `TextRenderInfo` object, you should operate like this (pseudo-code):

```
if (unprocessedTextRenderInfos not empty)
{
    if (isNewLine // Check this like the simple text extraction strategy checks for hardReturn
     || isGapFromPrevious) // Check this like the simple text extraction strategy checks whether to insert a space
    {
        process(unprocessedTextRenderInfos);
        unprocessedTextRenderInfos.clear();
    }
}

split new TextRenderInfo using its getCharacterRenderInfos() method;
while (characterRenderInfos contain word end)
{
    add characterRenderInfos up to excluding the white space/punctuation to unprocessedTextRenderInfos;
    process(unprocessedTextRenderInfos);
    unprocessedTextRenderInfos.clear();
    remove used render infos from characterRenderInfos;
}
add remaining characterRenderInfos to unprocessedTextRenderInfos;
```

In `process(unprocessedTextRenderInfos)` you extract the information you need from the unprocessedTextRenderInfos; you concatenate the individual text contents to a word and take the coordinates you want; if you merely want starting coordinates, you take those from the first of those unprocessed TextRenderInfos. If you need more data, you also use the data from the other TextRenderInfos. With these data you fill a "word with position" structure and add it to your result list.

When page processing is finished, you have to once more call process(unprocessedTextRenderInfos) and unprocessedTextRenderInfos.clear(); alternatively you may do that in the `endTextBlock` method.

Having done this, you might feel ready to implement the slightly more complex variant which does not have the same assumptions concerning the page content structure. ;)

Comment: Hi there! I followed this solution and I "almost" got it, excluding that I'm breaking my head trying to get every specific word's coordinates (the rectangle itself) inside the initial chunk's rectangle. Is there any "easy" way to perform this? Actually, I'm extracting every word inside the TextChunk and figuring out the coordinate based on the actual Left, Right and so on. Am I doing it on the right way? Thank you so much for that explanation!

Comment: @Gonzo345 Have you considered the step `split new TextRenderInfo using its getCharacterRenderInfos() method`? In that step you get a `TextRenderInfo` for each glyph, in particular, therefore, for each glyph starting or ending a word. If you have considered that and don't get ahead nonetheless, please create an actual stack overflow question providing enough code and a sample document for reproducing the issue.